# need to keep sending data to client from server(nodejs)

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am writing a router which stream tweets from twitter API and keep sending me tweets, i want to display these tweets on browser(i.e, i need to send response to the browser continously). Lets say response is sended after each tweets.
I am facing the problem like i can only send response once for each request.
I am attaching the code. Can i send multiple response for single request.

```
router.get('/:AddKey', function(req,res,next){
  const id = req.params.AddKey
  var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: id })
  console.log("asa");
  stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
  console.log(tweet);
  res.send(tweet);
  });

})
```

Comment: You also might wanna look into WebSockets.

Answer (score 0):

You can only send one response, what you can do however is putting the data which you want to send in an array.

```
router.get('/:AddKey', function(req,res,next){
  const id = req.params.AddKey
  var stream1 = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: id })
  var stream2 = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: id })
  console.log("asa");

  var data = [];

  stream1.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
  data.push(tweet);

  stream2.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
  console.log(tweet);
  data.push(tweet);

  // send the array:
 res.send(data)

  });

});
```

The actual implementation might be slightly different, but the concept is just put the multiple entities which you want to send in an array and send the array with res.send. [res.send](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) accepts strings, buffers, and arrays.

Comment: this is not exactly what i want. I wish i can stream the response. This will work when i have to store the data for some time and then i can send the stored data once. btw thnx for ur response :)